# Integer triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $xyz+4(x+y+z)=2(xy+yz+zx)+7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can we find integer triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $xyz+4(x+y+z)=2(xy+yz+zx)+7$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(x-2)(y-2)(z-2)$

$=(xy-2x-2y+4)(z-2)$

$=xyz-2xz-2yz+4z-2xy+4x+4y-8$

$=-1$

This means that all three factors are $-1$ or one of them is $-1$ and the other two $1$. Work from there.